# How to catch Broken pipe exception when send something using Ktor HttpClient(CIO) websocket?

Tags: android, websocket, ktor

I'm developing network App using Ktor 1.2.5 and Kotlin 1.3.61 in Android 8

When netty websocket server is shutdown ungracefully like recent app clean, websocket client does not receive any event.
At that time, if websocket client send something to server, then the App is crashed after happened Broken pope exception.
But, this Broken pipe exception does not catch at send.
Where to catch Broken pipe exception?

Here is exception log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.example.chatkt1, PID: 805
    java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:512)
        at io.ktor.network.sockets.CIOWriterKt$attachForWritingDirectImpl$1$1.invokeSuspend(CIOWriter.kt:75)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuation.resumeWith(Dispatched.kt:108)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.io.internal.CancellableReusableContinuation.resumeWith(CancellableReusableContinuation.kt:93)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.io.ByteBufferChannel.resumeReadOp(ByteBufferChannel.kt:2211)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.io.ByteBufferChannel.flushImpl(ByteBufferChannel.kt:156)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.io.ByteBufferChannel.flush(ByteBufferChannel.kt:162)
        at io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.WebSocketWriter.drainQueueAndSerialize(WebSocketWriter.kt:108)
        at io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.WebSocketWriter.writeLoop(WebSocketWriter.kt:47)
        at io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.WebSocketWriter$writeLoop$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is the websocket client code

```
fun sendToServer(message: String) {
    if(session != null) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            mutex.withLock {
                try {
                    session!!.send(message)
                    session!!.flush()
                } catch (e: IOException) {              
                    if (e.message.equals("Broken pipe")) {
                        println("catch Broken pipe exception")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can set an exception handler https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler) for all threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with referring Aleksei Tirman's comment.

```
 val old = Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        if (e is java.io.IOException && e.message.equals("Broken pipe")) {
            println("catch Broken pipe exception")
        } else {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
            exitProcess(10);
        }
    }
```

It works well.